# Why is Contribute Being Required At the Site Level?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are running SharePoint 2013. I'm running into the oddest issue. On other SharePoint setups I was able to give everyone read access at the site level and then different groups contribute access to various lists. For some reason with this site, contribute permissions on a library will not work unless the person has contribute permission on the parent site.

Has anyone ran into this? The little bit I've been able to gather is that it has to do with content types. I'm not using any custom content types, just the default for the library. I'm stumped as this should be basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the different groups from scratch? If so, and if the only permission you set for that group is "Contribute" on the library, you might also need to grant it the "Limited Access" permission at the site level.